# I am not able to parameterized a variable with a variable in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am getting a `Json` response in an object and accessing the object using the field name to get the value.

So code is like:

```
${OBJECT}=  Evaluate  json.loads('''${RESPONSE.content}''')  json
```

`log  ${OBJECT["ID"]}` -> Now here i am not able to pass variable where i have passed "ID".

I am trying like: log  `${OBJECT[${VARIABLE}]}` But, it is giving me an error.

Can anyone comment what needs to fix here. Thanks!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error.

Comment: addition to what Bryan mentioned above comment is how the json looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the variable in quotes when querying the `${OBJECT}` array.

Like so:

```
Log  ${OBJECT['${VARIABLE}']}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Read JSON variable-based field
    ${JSON}=  Set Variable  {"name": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}
    ${FIELD_VARIABLE}=  Set Variable  lastName
    ${OBJECT}=  Evaluate  json.loads('''${JSON}''')  json
    Log To Console  ${OBJECT['${FIELD_VARIABLE}']}
```

Comment: Thank you `@joonas` for your response.

I have tried and some how it is working fine now `${OBJECT['${VARIABLE}']}`.
The only change i did is I have declared the `variable` inside `single quotes`.